# Some UV map islands are part of larger islands but are separated from them...how to compact them?

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I'm trying to learn how works UV maps and how to texture laying-out body uvs. I don't know how to explain the problem using very technical terms because I'm a newbie in blender and I don't speak english as primary language. I don't know why the uv map of my mesh is composed by some fragmented islands while the others seems to be more compact. I can move a lot of islands by clicking mouse at any point on their area,but some of them are part of larger islands but are separated from them and I can't move them by clicking the mouse on a point of their area,but I have to select everything. Is there a way to optimize them ? Also because character mesh seems to have no problems. I hope that the attached screenshot is self explanatory. Thanks.

[image: UV maps situation]

Comment: If you ask about the fact that you see selection in several areas of UV map while you selected only one island, then the reason is that the latter in this part has connection to another island on UV map. This depends on model and might be ok (not always).

Comment: problem could be that I don't know how to color the fragmented uv maps because they are not a plan surfaces...

Comment: Infact,please tell me how can I color this uv map : http://psychonews.it/dati/2016-03-13_22-45-15.png

Comment: did it. check here : http://psychonews.it/dati/2016-03-14_21-38-45.png ; what should I do now ?

Comment: Now you can see how much distortion does UV map have. All those squares should be of roughly the same size and form. In your case they aren't. The problem now is how to apply seams correctly instead of current ones, keeping in mind that seams should be hidden in unvisible parts of mesh. This means composing another question about correcting this UV map but asking it may be out of scope of this site, so try on http://community.cgcookie.com or http://blenderartists.org.

Comment: clear seams and re do mark seams may help ?